# Want to query in redshift all transaction from last month from the first day to end

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
select date, count(*)
from public.asm_insights
where date > 
dateadd(MONTH, -1,GETDATE())
group by date
```

i want to get the number of records from the first day of last month to last day of that month. how can i improve my query? i am using redshift so DATEPART() didnt worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For the date filtering you can use:

```
select date, count(*)
from public.asm_insights i
where date < date_trunc('month', current_date) and
      date >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month'
group by date;
```

Comment: from sone reason it is still giving also the day; date_trunc('month', current_date) which is the first of the month

Comment: @meitale . . . This returns all dates in the previous calendar month, which appears to be what your question is asking for.